Hölder's inequality for trace-class maps of $p$-liquid spaces and a related conjecture of Grothendieck
In Condensed Math and Complex Geometry Proposition 8.8, Clausen-Scholze describe trace-class maps between projective objects in the $p$-liquid category as sums of rank 1 operators against ${<}p$-summable sequences. This description suggests that there should be a version of the Hölder inequality for such operators.
There is a similar definition of $p$-summable operators in Grothendieck's Produits tensoriels topologiques et espaces nucléaires Chapter 2 Section 1: for $E, F$ Banach spaces, $L^p(E, F)$ is the set of all sums $\sum_i \lambda_i x_i^\prime \otimes y_i$ for $(\lambda_i) \in \ell^p$ and $(x_i^\prime)$ resp. $(y_i)$ a bounded sequence in $E^\prime$ resp. $F$.
In Theorem 3 of that section, Grothendieck proves the following estimate of Hölder's inequality:
if $u_i \in L^{p_i}(E, E)$, then the composite $u_1 u_2 \cdots u_n \in L^r(E,E)$, where
$$
\frac{1}{r} = \Big( \sum_i \frac{1}{p_i} \Big) - \frac{n+1}{2}.
$$
In Remark 1 Grothendieck conjectures that the estimate can be improved. I think Grothendieck's proof can be straightforwardly transferred to the $p$-liquid setting, so I'm curious: was Grothendieck's conjecture ever (fully or partially) resolved?
